# How do i delete rows that contains just a specific word in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[0,1,2,3], C=["Ghana","Nigeria","Africa","South Africa"]))
df[~df.C.str.contains("Africa")]
```

I want to delete the row with with only "Africa" without deleting the row with "South Africa"

Comment: simply `df[df['C'].ne('Africa')]`?

Comment: or would you match other combinations with "Africa", just not "South Africa"?